# Testing for a space character inside a string...?

Tags: c++, string, space

I'm trying to test if a character in a string is a space, and I'm getting extremely frustrated:

```
string my_string;
cin >> my_string;
for (int i = 0; i < my_string.length(); i++)
    {
        if (my_string[i] == ' ') // this never becomes true...
        {
            cout << "this text should pop, but never does" << endl;
        }
    }
```

I'm not getting any errors and I've looked online, but people on different forums say this is how to test for a space. Uh.

Comment: Should work. Does my_string really contain spaces?

Comment: @Pete: my_string will never contain a space because the formatted read reads a single *word*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

when you say

```
cin >> my_string;
```

you are taking *formatted input*. `std::cin` discards any whitespace in that line, and it reads up to and yields only a single word.

try instead

```
std::string my_string;
std::getline(std::cin, my_string);
```

to get a single line, or

```
#include <iterator>

// ...
std::string my_string((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cin)),
                      std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

to get everything up to an end-of-file mark into the string.

Comment: What would i use if i wanted to eliminate the trailing '\n'?

Comment: @vorbis getline throws is away

Comment: `std::getline()` gives you a line without the trailing newline character. All of the members of the `getline()` family of functions behave this way, discarding the delimiter when reached.

Answer (score 5):

Thats because cin stops reading at the first whitespace so you never actually read the entire sentence but the first word. Use getline instead.

```
std::string my_string;
std::getline(std::cin, my_string);
for (int i = 0; i < my_string.length(); i++)
    {
        if (my_string[i] == ' ') // this never becomes true...
        {
            std::cout << "this text should pop, but never does" << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Really? I've typed in sentences before using a single cin and its been able to return ever character back to me.

Comment: Yup. Try cout<<m_string and see what's being stored.

Answer (score 2):

Additionnally to test whether a space is present use [`std::string::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)!

```
std::string my_string;
std::cin >> my_string; // please do not use « using namespace std; » if possible
size_t space_position = my_string.find(' ');
if(space_position != std::string::npos)
{
    std::cout << "found space" << std::endl;
}
```